# Grant users access to directories on partition

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, mount, permissions, automount

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04.  The OS and binaries are on an SSD.  All of the data and files are on a standard HDD.  The system's other user accounts each have a directory on the HDD.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to grant users access to their partitions.  I have created symbolic links from their home directories, on the SSD, to their directories on the HDD.  However, the permissions must be messed up since they can't see the contents of their directories.

I did try to use `chown` to set the permissions.  So for a user named `john` I did the following to their data directory (on the HDD): `sudo chown john:john -R /media/myusername/HDD/John`

This doesn't grant them access, unfortunately.  Should I be mounting the HDD to /media/ instead of its automount location, which is `/media/myusername`?

To be clear, I want users to have access to their own directories on the HDD, but not anyone else's.  Otherwise, I would just change the entire disk's permissions to 777.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd mount it in `/mnt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount the drive in `/mnt` or `/media` so all users can get to it. Then `chown` each of their directories to be owned by them and their group. To keep everyone else out `chmod 770`. And in your example I would drop the `-R` Just give the main directory no permissions for the world and no one but the user will be able to get in.

EX:
user john has folder in top level of drive called john and the drive is mounted at `/mnt/drive`

`sudo chown john:john /mnt/drive/john`

`sudo chmod 770 /mnt/drive/john`